# How I can solve AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'nemitx' error and Keyerror?

Tags: python

How I can solve

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'nemitx' error and Keyerror?

```
class TwissGaussBeam(GaussBeam):
    '''__init__(self, twiss, N=1000, pos=np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]),
    Q=1e-9, chargesign=-1, restmass=ele_mass)
    Create a multi-particle beam with a Gaussian spread in each of the 
    6 dimensions.  The statistics of the beam distribution are calculated
    from the Twiss parameters in twiss.'''

def __init__(self, twiss, N=100000, pos=np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), 
    Q=1e-12, chargesign=-1, restmass=ele_mass):
    P = pos[5]
    gammasquared = ( (P*1e6)**2 + restmass**2 ) / restmass**2
    betagamma = np.sqrt(gammasquared - 1)
    sig = np.zeros(6)
    sig[0] = np.sqrt((twiss.nemitx/betagamma) * twiss.betax)
    sig[1] = np.sqrt((twiss.nemitx/betagamma) / twiss.betax)
    sig[2] = np.sqrt((twiss.nemity/betagamma) * twiss.betay)
    sig[3] = np.sqrt((twiss.nemity/betagamma) / twiss.betay)
    sig[4] = twiss.sigz
    sig[5] = twiss.sigP
```

Comment: The error message is because Python doesn't think the twiss object has a nemitx member.  The solution is to fix that.  I actually took the time to google "twiss" and 'twiss multi particle beam."  I came up empty.  Since you didn't tell us anything at all about this twiss object that's being passed in, it's just about impossible to help you.  Please read [ask], and give us enough information such as an [mcve], so we can attempt to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I have not given enough information. Next time I'll consider your points and thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome to add the necessary information to your question. SO questions and answers are expected to improve iteratively. No one ever writes a perfect first question. If you did find that Michael's answer was useful, upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that twiss is a dictionary object, the correct way to access the Value for Key - nemitx would be thus:

```
twiss['nemitx']
```

This would be the same for betax, sigz, and sigP.

You can read more about Python dictionaries here:

[Data Structures Python - Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: This is jumping to a lot of conclusions. It is better waiting for clarification either in the comments or edited in the question. This question can't be answered currently.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, it works. I am new to Python and always confused how to use objects in class.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this since the user confirmed via right answer that he wanted to access  the key `'nemitx'` of his dictionary `'twiss'`.

The error has occurred because probably you were trying to access your dictionary key with an expression like `twiss.nemitx`, instead of the right one `twiss['nemitx']`.

Actually `twiss.nemitx` in Python would indicate that you are trying to access the attribute `nemitx` of the object `twiss`, and that would explain why you are getting an [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references):

> If this attribute is not available, the exception AttributeError is
>   raised.